# Couchbase RBAC expropriation of dependence

Tags: couchbase, rbac

I have to provide some functionality that will let me create users with a custom set of permissions by assigning them some combination of existing roles for couchbase. 
For example I want to have *role* **X** that will be equal to those [couchbase roles](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/cli/cbcli/couchbase-cli-user-manage.html): **query_select**, **fts_searcher** and **data_monitoring**.

The problem is that I couldn't find way to conclude which roles will be inherited. This is only shown with browser API when you choose Admin or Cluster Admin role, but there are more of those cases.

[image: Couchbase browser api - add user]

---

When I'm creating those roles in [Python SDK](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/python/start-using-sdk.html) or using [couchbase-cli](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/cli/cbcli-intro.html) there is like 0 verification on that, so then even Admin role does not exclude the ones it inherit (see **u01**).

[image: Couchbase user list]

There is some info in documentation that helps me deal with that but it doesn't cover all of it.
[RBAC for Administrators](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/security/concepts-rba.html) and
[RBAC for Applications](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/security/concepts-rba-for-apps.html)

Is there any faster way than testing it out manually?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JohanLarson thanks for vigilance. 
Do you have any sources or ideas that could help me with that?

Comment: hey Avix, unfortunately the notion of custom roles is not part of the current RBAC implementation.  We're in the process right now of looking at "user groups" for a future release, I suspect that will address many of your needs.

You're right that the UI provides a bit of extra logic in terms of role assignment, it doesn't align exactly to the actual role definitions at the API level.


Would you be able to elaborate a bit more on what you're looking to accomplish?  I'll also make a note to improve the documentation for you, it's another area we're working on.

Comment: @Perrykrug Thanks for your answer! That's great, groups would help a lot. 
If it's about more information: I implemented simple wrapper that provides me something like this: add_user --role my_custom_role --bucket ... 
And I provide some json that describes those custom roles using the ones that couchbase provides. Now to improve that I would like to know which couchbase roles inherit anothers e.g. I set couchbase role to data_backup -> do I have any other cb roles with that (maybe it provides me data_reader)?

Comment: Thanks Dawid, that's helpful.  I will ask our doc team to review your request and update accordingly.  In addition, I would love to get some more direct feedback about what sort of role combinations you're creating and also how you're using the product in general.  Could you reach out to me at perry -at- couchbase -dot- com?